# Gitlab CI: terraform destroy doesn't destroy?

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci

I have defined the following, simple pipeline:

```
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

variables:
  PLAN: dbrest.tfplan
  STATE: dbrest.tfstate

cache:
  paths:
    - .terraform

before_script:
  - terraform --version
  - terraform init

stages:
  - validate
  - build
  - deploy
  - destroy

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate

plan:
  stage: build
  script:
    - terraform plan -state=$STATE -out=$PLAN
  artifacts:
    name: plan
    paths:
      - $PLAN
      - $STATE

apply:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: production
  script:
    - terraform apply -state=$STATE -input=false $PLAN
    - terraform state show aws_instance.bastion
  dependencies:
    - plan
  when: manual
  only:
    - master

destroy:
    stage: destroy
    environment:
      name: production
    script:
      - terraform destroy -state=$STATE -auto-approve
    dependencies:
      - apply
    when: manual
    only:
      - master
```

When I run it, everything succeeds wonderfully - but the `destroy` stage doesn't in fact destroy the environment I've created in the `apply` stage. This is what I see:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.5.0 (80b03db9)
  on ip-10-74-163-110 5cf66672
Using Docker executor with image hashicorp/terraform:light ...
Pulling docker image hashicorp/terraform:light ...
Using docker image sha256:5d5c9faad78b96bb84555a584fe729260d7ff7d3fb973e105690ddc0dab48fb5 for hashicorp/terraform:light ...
Running on runner-5cf66672-project-1136-concurrent-0 via ip-10-197-79-116...
Fetching changes...
Removing .terraform/
Removing dbrest.tfplan
Removing dbrest.tfstate
HEAD is now at f798b05 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
Checking out f798b05a as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for default-1...
Successfully extracted cache
$ terraform --version
Terraform v0.12.13
+ provider.aws v2.34.0
$ terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...

The following providers do not have any version constraints in configuration,
so the latest version was installed.

To prevent automatic upgrades to new major versions that may contain breaking
changes, it is recommended to add version = "..." constraints to the
corresponding provider blocks in configuration, with the constraint strings
suggested below.

* provider.aws: version = "~> 2.34"

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
$ terraform destroy -state=$STATE -auto-approve

Destroy complete! Resources: 0 destroyed.
Creating cache default-1...
.terraform: found 5 matching files                 
Created cache
Job succeeded
```

It seems obvious that something is missing in the way I call `terraform destroy`, but I don't know what - can somebody shed some light on this, please?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Why didn't you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't correctly passing the state from the `apply` job because you haven't set the artifacts up like you did for `plan` -> `apply`. Your `apply` job should look like this:

```yaml
apply:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: production
  script:
    - terraform apply -state=$STATE -input=false $PLAN
    - terraform state show aws_instance.bastion
  artifacts:
    name: apply
    paths:
      - $STATE
  dependencies:
    - plan
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

A better solution, however, would be to not use file based state here and instead use proper [remote state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote.html) (eg [S3](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html) if you're using AWS) or you're going to have a ton of problems later on when multiple users (including CI as a potentially self concurrent user) are running Terraform. This allows you to take advantage of [state locking](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/locking.html) and also allow for versioning the state file in case things go wrong during a Terraform operation such as moving state as part of a refactor.